# Apache log sorting most visited ip

Tags: shell

```
cat access.log | grep -o "[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}" | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I don't understand this statement. Somebody please explain.

Comment: Seems overly complicated to me.  Piping `cat` into `grep` is unnecessary, and so is piping `grep` into `awk`.  Assuming `access.log` is a common webservr log or similar, the IP address or hostname is **always** the **first** field, so you can use this instead: `awk '{print $1}' access.log | sort -V | uniq -c | sort -n`.  BTW, a version sort (`-V`) is better to use with IP addresses than a numeric sort (`-n`), but requires GNU sort.  Produces a list of unique IP addresses/hostnames in the log, sorted by the number of times each one appeared.  Alternatively, use `cut -d' ' -f1` instead of `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

it reads a log file, matches IPs and counts them...

man grep says:

```
 -o, --only-matching
              Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

man sort says:

```
-n, --numeric-sort
              compare according to string numerical value
```

man uniq says:

```
-c, --count
              prefix lines by the number of occurrences
```

Answer (score 1):

The line processes "access.log", and filters for lines with ip4 addresses (4 times 1 to 3 numbers with dots in between).

Then it sorts the output numerically (first sort -n), removes duplicates (uniq), and sorts again...

The second sort may be ommitted i think.

Comment: yes, the second is odd

Comment: `uniq -c` **counts** the unique lines, and the second sort (`sort -n`) sorts the output of `uniq -c` by the numeric count.  `sort ... | uniq -c | sort -n` is a fairly common shell-scripting phrase.